# AngularJS - First run of .service plans to send data, but none shows, second run, no plans to send data, but some shows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following call inside my controller:

```
.controller('OverviewCtrl', function($http, $rootScope, $scope, tipService, alertService) {

    var user = $rootScope.sessionUser;

    alertService.getAlert(user).then(function(payload) {
        $scope.newAlerts = payload;
        console.log('got new alerts: ' + $scope.newAlerts);
        $rootScope.unreadAlerts = $scope.newAlerts.length;
    });
});
```

And here is the alertService:

```
.service('alertService', function($rootScope) {
var getAlert = function(user) {
    var newAlerts = [];
    //function calling business logic for eligible alerts
    //set up database query (using Parse)
    query.equalTo("user", user);
    return query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var oldAlerts = results;
            for (var i=0; i<alerts.length; i++) {
                var isNew = true;
                for (var j=0; j<oldAlerts.length; j++) {
                    if (alerts[i].get("callout") === oldAlerts[j].attributes.callout) {
                        isNew = false;
                    }
                }
                if (isNew) {
                    newAlerts.push(alerts[i]);
                    alertToSave = alerts[i];
                    alertToSave.save(null, {
                        success: function(alert) {
                            console.log('successfully saved alert: ' + alert.get("callout"));
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log('Failed to save new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            console.log('about to return new alerts: ' + newAlerts);
            return newAlerts;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
};

return {
    getAlert: getAlert
};
});
```

What's weird is that the first time this is run (assume there are actually two new alerts), the console.log says this:

about to return new alerts: [object Object],[object Object]

got new alerts:

But the second time this is run, the console.log says this:

about to return new alerts:

got new alerts: [object Object],[object Object]

What's going on? What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

For whatever reason, the service was returning the results of the query, not the newAlerts array. As a workaround, I just moved this code into a function in the controller and kept just the business logic for finding eligible alerts in the service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that the alerts array is defined, Nor is anything added to the alerts array. So each time you compare the results/oldAlerts to the alerts array nothing has changed.

I'm not sure why the controller doesn't see anything till the second round.  Try using a debugger to step through your code line by line as this should give you a better idea of what is happening

Comment: Sorry, the alerts array gets declared where I type '//function calling business logic for eligible alerts'

Comment: I am starting to suspect that it is not actually returning newAlerts, it is returning the result of the query (which requires a 'return' or the function in the controller is undefined). That would explain why it returns nothing in the first and both in the second call. Is this possible? If so, how do I get it to return newAlerts?

Comment: My suspicion was correct, it is returning the results of the query. Hmmmmm, how to force it to return newAlerts?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the service was returning the results of the query, not the newAlerts array. As a workaround, I just moved this code into a function in the controller and kept just the business logic for finding eligible alerts in the service.